# ios: button in custom table cell not respond when scroll

Tags: ios, button, cell, tablecell

Sorry for my poor English. I want to add some clickable buttons in my custom tablecell and it works fine but i face a problem when i scroll down the table. After scrolling, the buttons in the upper cell will have no response when i click on it. but when i scroll back to the original position of the cell, the buttons have response again.

I put this

```
[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method; 
and `btnPressed` had been triggered before i scroll down. but `btnPressed` cannot be triggered after i scroll out the bound of the original position of that cell.

Hope someone can understand my problem thanks.
Please tell me how can I make the button response even the table scroll ? thanks in advance

---

**method 1**

when i tried the method addtarget in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the coding is like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";
            CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) 
            return cell;
}
```

---

**method 2**

i also tried another method which do not addtarget in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Here's my code with delegate

in customcell.h, i added this

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didClickOnbtn;
@end
```

in customcell.m,  i added this

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *currentDict;
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<CustomCellDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

and

```
- (IBAction)didClickOnbtn:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickOnbtn)]) {
        [self.delegate didClickOnbtn];
    }
}
```

and i have set the custom cell delegate to the tableview

in tabelview controller i also have the method `didClickOnbtn` and `<CustomCellDelegate>`

and the button can trigger `didClickOnbtn` method in tableview controller response before scrolling the table.

---

UPDATE:
I had made a section header view in the table. And I find out when i delete the section header view, the problem is solved. Although I don't know why the section header view would make the button disable, it works well now. Hope this can help someone who are in the same situation as me.

p.s. Both methods work.

Comment: add log statement to check if button is  receving action or not .if yes then add tag value for each button in cellForRowAtIndexPath method while creating tableview cells. and perform actions based on the tag value

Comment: thanks for the reply it received action before scrolling

Comment: Show full code of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: `delaysContentTouches` set to `YES` (on UIScrollView, i.e. the superclass of UITableView) can sometimes give the illusion of buttons not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used the workaround to use Touch Down instead of Touch Up Inside. It's not a perfect solution but a work around as the IBAction for Touch Down as being called even when scrolling is not finished.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the frame of button ?
    is it in reference to cell frame ? or hardcode like below

```
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"MyButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0); // example co-ordinate
    [cell addSubview :button] ;
```

In this case , after scrolling down the button co-ordinate will not change and wont work as u said best way to make it right is

create a interface file for UITableViewCell , place a button there and do the wiring 
this will solve the scroll problem for you. 
also you can try doing this .

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+samplevalue ,cell.frame.origin.y+sampleValue , 160.0, 40.0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i tried to add button in my custom cell view and have method - (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender; but still having the same problem T_T

Answer (score 0):

Adding target for a button in a tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath: API is not not recommended way. This API gets called mutiple times when app needs to display the cell.

Move this code to cell class. Create custom class if not done and add this code. In the action method of the button, reference your controller and call some API that does action work for the cell (say open up other controller or so). You can make your view controller as delegate of the cell for this purpose.

Hope this change may solve your problem

Comment: thanks for the reply. i had also tried this method but problems still cant be solved

Comment: Post your table view data source method calls, Unless looking at the code, doesnt come to know what the problem is.

Comment: In method 2, are you getting call to didClickOnbtn in cell class?

Comment: Then you are saying, if you do this after scrolling, then it is not working?

Comment: yes, it works when its cell back to the original position (not scroll or scroll back the corresponding position)

Comment: In method 2, how are you adding action method to button?

Comment: i drag the button to the method in the xib and .h

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to add the button to second cell of tableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell1";
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
   //Add button to cell and use different reuseIdentifier
   UITableViewCell *cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"btnCell"];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell1.frame.origin.x+10, cell1.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width-20, cell1.frame.size.height-10)];
    [button setTitle:@"ButtonTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    shareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell1 addSubview:button];
    [shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell1;
}

//Your code...

return cell;
}
```